# ImportError on "import pillow" libraries installed in conda's list

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I have installed pillow and pimpmypillow on windows x86 in Anaconda.  When I enter conda list into the command prompt both are listed.  However when I run a python script in the shell that includes `import pillow` I get the message `ImportError no module named pillow.`

I am unable to connect to pip because of proxy errors

I get the same error with `pimpmypillow.`

pillow was downloaded from pypi.python.org as a `whl` and `pimpmypillow` was also downloaded from pypi.python.org as as tar.gz and installed using python setup.py install.

As I say both are in condas list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libraries probably installed correctly. The problem is with your import.

Pillow is the name of a library that provides an alternate implementation of the Python `PIL` package. The package is what you import, regardless of the library or project name. The confusion comes from the fact that 99% (not a real statistic) of the libraries on PyPi provide a package with the same name as the library.

You can look at the [Pillow tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html) for examples of how to use the library properly. You will notice that all the imports are done like

```
from PIL import Image
```

NOT

```
from pillow import Image
```